# Take color as input and change the background and foreground color repeatedly till user clicks cancel button

Tags: javascript

I have this question at hand: Prompt the user to enter his favorite background and foreground color. Receive the values and apply the same as the page’s background and foreground. Keep prompting the user for these details until the user says no(press cancel button).

This is what I did so far:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Color change</title>
  </head>

  <body>
  <p id="msg">Test sentence</p>
  <button onclick=myFunction()>Input</button>
  <script>
    function myFunction(){

      do{
        var a=prompt("Input backgroud color.","red");
        document.body.style.backgroundColor=a;
        var b=prompt("Input foreground color.","green");
        document.body.style.color=b;
      }while(a!="");
    }

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This code just keep asking for input and does not reflect any change in color. I want the color to be changed after each input till user clicks cancel.
Any suggestion will be useful. Thanks.

Comment: Your code works fine

Comment: @HoussemBdr but not reflecting the changes after each loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While loop blocks the browser from reflecting your change, use this code snippet:

```
<button onclick="changeColor()">Input</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeColor() {
    let a = prompt("Input backgroud color.", "red");
    if (a !== '') {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = a;
        let b = prompt("Input foreground color.", "green");
        document.body.style.color = b;
        window.setTimeout(changeColor, 0);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: can you please let me know why while loop blocks the changes?

Comment: It relies on the browser's implementation, but I found that most browsers don't update DOM when your script is still running.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `requestAnimationFrame`

callback will be recalled after frame is ready

```js
function myFunction() {
    var colors = ['red', 'green'];
    var i = 0,
        input = 1;

    function callback() {
        input = prompt("Input backgroud color.", colors[i++ % colors.length]);
        if (input && ~colors.indexOf(input)) {
            document.body.style.color = input;
            window.requestAnimationFrame(callback);
        }
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(callback);
}
```

```html
Test sentence
<button onclick=myFunction()>Input</button>
```