# Why Chrome doesn't show applied html changes until the prompt got cancelled?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

Let me clear it.

The program which I wrote **prompts** for a name and then looks for it among an array of objects. if it finds the name then print the name and other details of that person in a `div`. it keep on searching until i type `quit`.

No problem with code. Just in **chrome** it does not **show** found results until I type `quit` (aka break the loop). I test my code in Firefox and it shows results immediately. Can you tell me why?

```js
var answer = '';
var html='';
var students = [
    {name:"peter",age:24,track:'front-end',achivements:15,scores:748},
    {name:"dave",age:23,track:'back-end',achivements:11,scores:433},
    {name:"leo",age:22,track:'front-end',achivements:14,scores:71},
    {name:"juan",age:21,track:'ios',achivements:22,scores:442},
    {name:"eli",age:26,track:'android',achivements:24,scores:711}
];


function printer (message){
    
    var div = document.getElementById("output");
    div.innerHTML += message;
}

  answer = prompt("Who are you looking for?");
  answer = answer.toLowerCase();

while (answer!='quit'){
    
    
        for (var z=0;z<students.length;z++){
        var student = students[z];
        if (answer=== student.name){
            html = ''
            html +='<p><b>Student: '+student.name+'</b></p>';
            html +='<p>Track: '+student.track+'</p>';
            html +='<p>Points: '+student.scores+'</p>';
            html +='<p>Achievements: '+student.achivements+'</p></br>';
            printer(html);    
            
                                    }

                                            }
    
        answer = prompt("Who are you looking for?");
        answer = answer.toLowerCase();
}
```

```css
@import url('http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.2/normalize.css');

/*General*/
body {
  background: #fff;
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font: Helvetica Neue, Helvectica, Arial, serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  color: #8d9aa5;
}

a {
  color: #3f8aBf;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #3079ab;
}

a:visited {
  color: #5a6772;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #384047;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.8em;
  margin: 60px 0 40px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 30px 0 10px 0;
}

#home h2 {
  margin: -40px 0 0;
}

h3 {
  font-size: .9em;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h3 em {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0 0 10px 5px;
  padding: 0;
  color: #8d9aa5;
}

ol {
  margin: 0 0 20px 32px;
  padding: 0;
}

#home ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0 40px 0;
}

li {
  padding: 8px 0;
  display: list-item;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  counter-increment: step-counter;
}

#home li::before {
    content: counter(step-counter);
    font-size: .65em;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: 2px 6px;
    margin:  0 18px 0 0;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background:#8d9aa5;
    line-height: 1em;
}

.lens {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid #8d9aa5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 5px 0 0 -19px;
}

#color div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 5px;
}

span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>List Of Students</title>
    
    

</head>
<body>
<h1>Found Students</h1>
<div id="output">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

call `prompt` with chrome browser will block page rendering.

use `requestAnimationFrame` or `setTimeout` can solve the problem

some answers are here [take color from prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45669952/take-color-as-input-and-change-the-background-and-foreground-color-repeatedly-ti/45670253#45670253)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome browser does not support `prompt`therefore chrome browser will automatically block page rendering. This may be because you have an older version of chrome, you may need to update.

To cut a long story short, you could just use one of these two

```
requestAnimationFrame 

setTimeout
```

I got my information from these websites:
https://css-tricks.com/using-requestanimationframe/
https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/met_win_setTimeout.asp